# SharePoint - Adding a user to a person or group field that allows multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have searched everywhere for a solution but I am not having any luck. What I am trying to do is, in a form append a variable value (username) to a person or group field that already has values in it. I want to achieve this through jquery or javascript. Please see below for an example

Person Field : usera, userb, userc

UserVar = userd

after code executes UserVar is appended to Person Field

Person Field : usera, userb, userc, userd

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? What kind of form is it (e.g. default SharePoint form/custom SharePoint Designer/custom InfoPath)? And finally, what's the overall context... why are you trying to fill in a person field on a form programmatically? (I'm asking just in case there's a better way to accomplish what you're ultimately trying to do, such as using a workflow or using JSOM/REST to update SharePoint directly.)

Comment: SharePoint 2010, SP Designer, custom form. I need to add the current user who is viewing the form to a person/group field without overwriting the assigned users or groups already in it.